# android text view in dialog box

Tags: java, android, textarea

hi i am a new android developer. In my app i have created a dialog box in text view which appears to be a pop up window. In that the content i type is to be in left alignment form how can i move it to be in center, just like a middle alignment form.....

Comment: please share the xml code of the layout, that you set on the dialog box.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Siva,

According to my understanding of your question, you want your text to be aligned to center, right ??? if yes then try this in your TextView:

```
android:gravity = "center_vertical|center"
```

Well, if it is not what you want then please explain your question a bit more.